# Percona 5.7 slow "Sending data" after upgrade from Mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, database, performance, upgrade, percona

After upgrading Mysql 5.5 to Percona 5.7 application move very slow.
I am unable to optimize the query because are compiled with the application
The only thing I can do is to optimize the MySQL server (or the server config)

I need to mention that I see some query that returns lots of data (70M of result)
Data dir is on SSD. I have 32G RAM, but I allocate 20 for Mysql (60% because we have also other small services)

I notice a small improvement if I activate cache (that will be deprecated)

[Bellow is my config](https://gist.github.com/costyoancea/0e82d57cf9fc47b5c89429196cf2c134)

[SHOW GLOBAL STATUS result is here](https://gist.github.com/costyoancea/a05cd504932cfa36e710932f99277790)

Do someone have some idea what to improve to MySQL config / or server to improve performance?
I put an SQL with explain as an example. It returns 672 rows of data but takes 30 seconds (29 stays in "Sending data").

```
explain select l.idCodeLocation as idLocation, l.txLocation as name, l.radius as radius, l.amLat as lat, l.amLong as lng, g.isin as isin, g.isout as isout, g.onval as onval, m.isGeofenceIn as isGeofenceIn, m.geofenceInTime as geofenceInTime, m.isGeofenceOn as isGeofenceOn, v.idVeh as idveh, v.idPlateVeh as plate, v.idClient as client from sat_geofence g left join sat_clientLocation as l on (g.idLocation=l.idCodeLocation) join sat_geofence_vehicle_mtm as m on (g.idLocation=m.idLocation) join sat_vehicle as v on (m.idVeh=v.idVeh);
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref               | rows   | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | g     | NULL       | ALL    | idx           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL              |     38 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | NULL       | ref    | idx           | idx     | 768     | Stdb.g.idLocation |      5 |   100.00 | Using index condition                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 3       | Stdb.m.idVeh      |      1 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL              | 116952 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

the tables structure I put here: https://gist.github.com/costyoancea/deee560f9c94aa2463162d7ce0556392

Thanks,
Costi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are MISSING an index on m.idVeh. m references sat_geofence_vehicle_mtm.  Make additional simple index with this in the First position, please.   For tuning assistance view my profile, Network profile for contact info, please.  And check out my reviews on the Shop page.

Comment: I change the index, but the same result. [Here are the new details.](https://gist.github.com/costyoancea/66a412385a0d943e5ea16a1492c114e4)

Comment: @user3692786 Could you post TEXT from your OS results of  ulimit -a  so we know your OS limits and results of  iostat -xm 5 3  and we will know how many cpu/cores you have available.

Comment: The CPU has 4 cores. [here details about CPU, ulimit and iostat](https://gist.github.com/costyoancea/d11a87229efcdd81ab3bba0dea9e1ab4)

Comment: let try tommorow to have a skype.

Answer (score 0):

```
group_concat_max_len = 18446744073709565  -- dangerously large.
```

Please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` to help with the tuning analysis.  How much RAM do you have?

Please show us the query even if you cannot change it.  We may be able to suggest an index that would help.

Comment: We have an isolated script that require this group_concat_max_len

Comment: We have 32GB of RAM, but we have other other services and I let for mysql aprox. 60%

Comment: I put a query with details as example

Comment: @user3692786 - Since `group_concat_max_len` is allocated in RAM, and you have only 32GB, you are asking for a crash.

Comment: I think we can change group_concat_max_len to be on the safe side and use like this only when we will run the script. But I don't think the performance problems are related to this

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for your Linux ulimit -a limits

```
ulimit -n 65536       to increase Open File limit from 1024
```

To allow this value to persist over Linux shutdown/restart, please review this content,

https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/

your details may be slightly different due to OS version.

Rate Per Second=RPS
Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
join_buffer_size=128K  # from 128M for a more reasonable RAM request per connection
sort_buffer_size=2M  # from ~256M for a more reasonable RAM request per connection
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to reduce CPU cycles used every SECOND
innodb_flushing_avg_loops=5  # from 30 to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty 5,692
table_open_cache=10000  # from 4096 to reduce opened_tables RPHr 40,456 
open_table_definitions=10000  # from 400 to reduce opened_table_definitions RPHr 21,459
thread_cache_size=100  # from 14 to reduce threads_created from 64
```

Looking forward to your feedback and a Review posted on my website after 7 days, please.

Comment: Hi. thanks for your advice, but I don't see any improvements after applying your recommendation.

Comment: Hi @wilson-hauck. I just upload [here](https://gist.github.com/costyoancea/0ae22d4fef946d25e19e74995183c830) the new info you require. Thank you again for your support.